# Issue in stopping an infinite loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following part of the code. I am reading frames from a folder at the rate of 5 frames per second, within an infinite loop and in total I have 2552 frames in folder.

I need to stop reading frames when all frames are read from folder, because the issue I am facing my code runs in an infinite loop and more frames are read than there are in folder. I don't want to change while running. How would I stop when all frames are read, hard-stopping or soft-stopping the infinite loop once the filenames-list was processed, once and only once.

```
filenames = [img for img in glob.glob("video-frames/*.jpg")]
fps = 5
interval = int(1 / fps)
while running: # INFINITE LOOP
    filenames = sorted(filenames, key=os.path.getctime)
    for img in filenames:
        frame = cv2.imread(img)
        frame_count += 1
        time.sleep(interval)
        send_frame(frame,frame_count) # REPEAT INFINITE LOOP
```

Comment: `break` out of it? Set `running` to a falsey value? There are many ways. Your code is not a complete example. You don't even show what `running` is...

Comment: Your code is not changing the value of `running`. Why do u need the while loop when you have the for loop.

Comment: `1/5` gives `0.20` but `int(1/5)` gives `0` - you shouldn remove `int()` - you can use `sleep(1/5)` to get 5 frames per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks over-thought and haphazard. I'd suggest breaking down your problem a bit more.

First off, your list comprehension isn't doing anything except wasting cpu cycles.
[glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) already returns a list.
so:

```
filenames = glob.glob("video-frames/*.jpg")
```

should suffice.

Second, just remove your `while true` statement.

```
filenames = sorted(filenames, key=os.path.getctime)
for img in filenames:
    frame = cv2.imread(img)
    frame_count += 1
    time.sleep(interval)
    send_frame(frame, frame_count) # no more infinite loop :)
```

This will stop once every jpg from the `filenames` list has been exhausted.

[If you aren't familiar with lists or iteration I'd suggest giving the doc a look](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)